# How come a compiler cannot detect if a global variable is changed by another thread?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, compilation, interrupt

I was just going through concepts of the `volatile` keyword. I just gone through [this link](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword), this link is telling about why to use the `volatile` keyword in case of program using interrupt handler. They have mentioned in one example:

```c
int etx_rcvd = FALSE;
void main()
{
    ...
    while (!ext_rcvd)
    {
        // Wait
    }
    ...
}

interrupt void rx_isr(void)
{
    ...
    if (ETX == rx_char)
    {
        etx_rcvd = TRUE;
    }
    ...
}
```

They are saying since compiler is not able to know `ext_rcvd` is getting updated in an interrupt handler. So compiler uses optimization intelligence and assumes that this variable value is always `FALSE` and it never enters into the `while{}` condition. So to prevent these situation we use `volatile` keyword, which stops compiler to use its own intelligence.

My question is, While compiling, how compiler is not able to know that `ext_rcvd` is getting updated in interrupt handler? PLease help me to find its answer, I am not getting correct answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot *analyze all the codes or running processes* that can modify the memory location of `ext_rcvd`.

In your example, you mentioned that `ext_rcvd` is being updated in an interrupt handler. That is correct. The interrupt handler is a piece of code launched by the Operating System, when the CPU receives an interrupt. That piece of code is actually the driver code. In the driver code, `ext_rcvd` **may have another name** but point to the same memory location.

So in order to know if `ext_rcvd` is updated somewhere else, the compiler needs to analyze the libraries and drivers' code and to figure out that they are updating the exact same memory location that you name `ext_rcvd` in your code. **This cannot be done before execution time.**

The same goes for multi-threading. The compiler cannot know a-priori if a certain thread is updating the exact memory location used by another thread. For example if another thread makes a `syscall()` then the compiler needs to look in the code handling the `syscall()`.

Answer (score 0):

When the CPU receives an interrupt, it stops whatever it's doing (unless it's processing a more important interrupt, in which case it will deal with this one only when the more important one is done), saves certain parameters on the stack and calls the interrupt handler. This means that certain things are not allowed in the interrupt handler itself, because the system is in an unknown state. The solution to this problem is for the interrupt handler to do what needs to be done immediately, usually read something from the hardware or send something to the hardware, and then schedule the handling of the new information at a later time (this is called the "bottom half") and return. The kernel is then guaranteed to call the bottom half as soon as possible -- and when it does, everything allowed in kernel modules will be allowed.

I think when the interrupt is called whatever is working is stopped and the variable is set to TRUE, not satisfying the while condition.
But when you use volatile keyword it makes C checks the variable value again.

Of course, I'm not 100% sure about this, I'm open for answers for change mine.

Comment: But my question is how compiler is not able to know that variable is getting updated by interupt handler. same thing happe in case of multi thread, compiler not able to know second thread is updating this value.Compilation is much before execution on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

`interrupt` is not a C specified keyword, so whatever is discussed is not C specified behavior.

Yes the compiler *could* see that `etx_rcvd` is modified inside an `interrupt` routine and therefore assume `etx_rcvd` could change at any time outside the interrupt function and make `int etx_rcvd` --> `volatile int etx_rcvd`.

Now the question is *should* it do that?

IMO: No, it is not needed.

An `interrupt` function could modify global variables and the code flow is such that non-interrupt functions access only happens in a interrupt protected block.  An optimizing compiler would be hindered by having implied `volatile` with `int etx_rcvd`.  So now code needs a way to say `non_volatile int etx_rcvd` to prevent the `volatile` assumption OP seeks.

C all ready provides a method to declare variables volatile (add `volatile`) and non-volatile (do not add `volatile`).  If an `interrupt` routine could make variables `volatile` without them being declared so, the code would need a new keyword to insure non-volatility.